# How do I Hide the Fact that my Webpage is iframed?

Tags: html, css, iframe

When I create a webpage with an iframe in it, the  tag get shown in the source code.

How do I hide the  tag?

Comment: Guess you cannot hide it from the source code and make it visible in the page. What is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really 'hide' a tag, but you could generate the iframe tag in Javascript. Is there lots of content inside the iframe tag?

If not, you could do for example, HTML:

```
<div id="innocentcontainer"></div>
```

then, in JS:

```
document.getElementById("innocentcontainer").innerHTML="<iframe something></iframe>";
```

Then you can load the javascript externally and it's pretty well hidden, though not if the user uses Firefox or Chrome, since they have a real-time DOM viewer :), and you'll never be able to fool them =D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The browser needs that tag, and you cannot hide the source from the user but not the browser.

Comment: You cannot *hide* the source, but you can *generate* the source...:)

Comment: ... which is usually only done by the people who know *how* to inspect, and if you want to hide something from *them*... well, there you go.

Comment: Then the question is, *who* are you actually trying to hide this from and why?!

Comment: Good question! Ask Joe I'd say!